# Stability of Model Predictive Controller

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, optimal-control

I appreciate if you suggest a reference that discusses the stability of Model Predictive Controller for continuous-time nonlinear systems.

Answer (score 1):

A useful reference on this subject is "Model predictive control of nonlinear systems: Computational burden and stability" by Chen, Ballance, and O'Reilly. Section 4 of that paper discusses stability in particular.